# MSAL4J aquire refresh_token and access_token to save instead of asking users for permission every time

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am currently strugling with implementation of the MS Graph api calls to access some of the information from Microsoft. I am especially interested in calendar. It would be nice to have the ability to add some events and remove them or scan for those events. Api for this usecase is pretty clear and even somehow intuitive.

I was able to trace back something that I am looking for which I already have seen in code but it is not a viable solution what so ever.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/issues/228

Microsoft staff kindly informs that they have nothing such mainstream in plans.
I have managed to get this authorization_code and call the api programatically, but it is going to be pain in the ass for users to reauthenticate themselves with MS Oauth every time token expires ( which is something around one hour ). I imagine such a tech giant has to have something up their sleeve which can be programmer-friendly.

Is there something else I can use?

Answer (score 1):

If using **MSAL** to get token, refresh token will be stored in the cache which is not exposed. We could get the new access token with `acquireTokenSilently`, see the code [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/blob/d55ee4ac0ce2c43378f2c99fd6e6856d41bdf144/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/msalwebsample/AuthHelper.java#L99).

```
    SilentParameters parameters = SilentParameters.builder(
            Collections.singleton("User.ReadBasic.All"),
            result.account()).build();

    CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireTokenSilently(parameters);
    IAuthenticationResult updatedResult = future.get();
```

If you would like get the refresh token **directly**, as the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/migrate-adal-msal-java#adal-to-msal-migration) shows, MSAL does not suppor it and ADAL4J will do.

> In ADAL4J, the refresh tokens were exposed--which allowed developers
> to cache them. They would then use `AcquireTokenByRefreshToken()` to
> enable solutions such as implementing long-running services that
> refresh dashboards on behalf of the user when the user is no longer
> connected.
>
> MSAL for Java does not expose refresh tokens for security reasons.
> Instead, MSAL handles refreshing tokens for you.
>
> MSAL for Java has an API that allows you to migrate refresh tokens you
> acquired with ADAL4j into the ClientApplication:
> [acquireToken(RefreshTokenParameters)](https://javadoc.io/static/com.microsoft.azure/msal4j/1.0.0/com/microsoft/aad/msal4j/PublicClientApplication.html#acquireToken-com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.RefreshTokenParameters-). With this method, you can
> provide the previously used refresh token along with any scopes
> (resources) you desire. The refresh token will be exchanged for a new
> one and cached for use by your application.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this. What If we need to be able to cache a refresh token ourselves? I understand maybe doing this in a mobile app because you have things like persistentParams, but how do you do this in an application that just uses maybe a db to store information (i'm trying to do this in a webapp for work). Don't we need to be able to have that refresh token between runtime stored somewhere so we can grab it on startup?

Comment: I found out how to cache the token information and set it for an acquireToken() call. I still have a question though, does MSAL not take care of getting a new refreshToken automatically then? What happens when it expires? Do we HAVE to use ADAL to renew refresh tokens? I can't seem to find a way to get a new refreshToken at all with MSAL

Comment: MSAL4J gets an access token and a refresh token when you first successfully call `acquireToken()`.  Both of these tokens are stored in the in-memory token cache, which is bound to your `PublicClientApplication` instance variable, e.g. `pca`.  That `pca` instance needs to be preserved (unless you're persisting the token cache to a JSON file) so you can later call `acquireTokenSilently()`.  When the current access token is near or beyond expiration and acquireTokenSiltently() succeeds, it will fetch a new access token and a new refresh token and put them both in the in-memory token cache.