# How to renew token using msal4j and Azure Blob Storage library

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

We are using Microsoft's Java library to access Azure Blob Storage, and the msal4j library to get the access token using the OAuth2 client access pattern.  Snippet below:

```
StorageCredentialsToken storageCredentialsToken = new StorageCredentialsToken(account_name, generateOAuthToken());
storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentialsToken, true);

private String generateOAuthToken() throws MalformedURLException {
  String authority = String.format(ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_ENDPOINT + "/%s/oauth2/v2.0/token", tenant_id);
  Set<String> scope = Collections.singleton(String.format("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/.default", account_name));
  IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(client_secret);
  ConfidentialClientApplication cca = ConfidentialClientApplication
      .builder(client_id, credential)
      .authority(authority)
      .build();
  ClientCredentialParameters parameters = ClientCredentialParameters
      .builder(scope)
      .build();
  IAuthenticationResult result = cca.acquireToken(parameters).join();
  return result.accessToken();
}
```

This works fine, but eventually the access token expires.  At this point operations start to fail.  In theory, there is a [refresh token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/refresh-tokens) that can be used to renew the access token, but it does not seem to be part of the IAuthenticationResult interface.  My questions are:

- Can tokens be renewed using this pattern?
- If not, what can be done?  Is there another pattern that supports renewal?  Or should I ignore renewal and just get a whole new access token?
- If I get a new access token, how do I install it into the existing `storageAccount` client? Can I just call `StorageCredentialsToken.updateToken()`, assuming I've kept that around?

UPDATE: response was quite helpful, but ultimately I could not get to a true token renewal when clientId/tenantId are in use.  This may be by design?  Regardless, simply acquiring a new token before expiry works, see following snippet:

```
IAuthenticationResult authResult = generateOAuthToken();
StorageCredentialsToken storageCredentialsToken = new StorageCredentialsToken(account_name, authResult.accessToken());
new Thread(new OAuthTokenRenewer(authResult, storageCredentialsToken)).start();
storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentialsToken, true);

private IAuthenticationResult generateOAuthToken() throws MalformedURLException {
  String authority = String.format(ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_ENDPOINT + "/%s/oauth2/v2.0/token", tenant_id);
  Set<String> scope = Collections.singleton(String.format("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/.default", account_name));
  IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(client_secret);
  ConfidentialClientApplication cca = ConfidentialClientApplication
      .builder(client_id, credential)
      .authority(authority)
      .build();
  ClientCredentialParameters parameters = ClientCredentialParameters
      .builder(scope)
      .build();
  return cca.acquireToken(parameters).join();
}


private class OAuthTokenRenewer implements Runnable {
  IAuthenticationResult authResult;
  final StorageCredentialsToken storageCredentialsToken;
  public OAuthTokenRenewer(IAuthenticationResult authResult, StorageCredentialsToken storageCredentialsToken) {
    this.authResult = authResult;
    this.storageCredentialsToken = storageCredentialsToken;
  }
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(60 * 1000L);
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (authResult.expiresOnDate().getTime() - now < RENEWAL_WINDOW_MS) {
          authResult = generateOAuthToken();
          storageCredentialsToken.updateToken(authResult.accessToken());
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenSilent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.aad.adal.authenticationcontext.acquiretokensilent?view=azure-java-stable):

The function will first look at the cache and automatically checks for the token expiration. Additionally, if no suitable access token is found in the cache, but refresh token is available, the function will use the refresh token automatically. This method will not show UI for the user. If prompt is needed, the method will return an exception

If using **MSAL** to get token, refresh token will be stored in the cache which is not exposed. We could get the new access token with acquireTokenSilently

```
SilentParameters parameters = SilentParameters.builder(
        Collections.singleton("User.ReadBasic.All"),
        result.account()).build();

CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireTokenSilently(parameters);
IAuthenticationResult updatedResult = future.get();
```

Reference: [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242530/msal4j-aquire-refresh-token-and-access-token-to-save-instead-of-asking-users-for)

Comment: Thanks, but can you complete the example?  Specifically, the declaration and creation of "app", and how the credentials are entered into the API.

Comment: Is "app" the ConfidentialClientApplication that I've named "cca"?

Comment: Also it seems that the "account" of SilentParameters is an IAccount.  How do I get that?  I looked at an MS-provided sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/blob/b37376b1fc481704b9b96b77170f01392f44bcaa/msal-b2c-web-sample/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/msalwebsample/AuthHelper.java#L43, but it gets complicated.

Comment: The MS example at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp gets an IAccount from an HttpServletRequest, but I do not have one of those, not being a web app.  How does one get an IAccount without that?

Comment: Ah, OK, I get it.  I have to auth first using my current method, get the IAuthenticationResult, which contains the IAccount, and then I can use the account in this snippet.  I'll verify this and mark as answer if it works.

Comment: Failed.  result.account() of my original IAuthenticationResult is null, so I'm stuck at "how do I get the IAccount"?

Comment: Is this document helps you please check with this  :https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-desktop/blob/master/Username-Password-Flow/src/main/java/UsernamePasswordFlow.java

Comment: Seems like the right idea, but not working.  My call to pca.getAccounts() returns an empty list.  I have an account name, but I don't see how to use it to get to the IAccount.

Comment: Please check with this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-java-get-remove-accounts-token-cache

Comment: I don't understand.  That page references the account cache, and shows that calling pca.getAccounts() will retrieve that cache.  But I'm calling that and it is empty.  Does something else need to be done to populate the cache?  Is there some other way to get an IAccount directly from the account name?

Comment: OK, at least I can see what should happen.  The exception handling of acquireTokenUsernamePassword builds a UsernamePasswordParameters to get the initial token.  However, I don't have a username/password, I have a clientId and tenantId.  Perhaps this token refresh flow is simply not available for clientId/tenantId authentication?  Am I forced to use username/password instead?

Comment: I'm marking this as an answer because @shrutijoshi-mt was quite persistent and this seems to lead to a solution for username/password.  I'll post an updated snippet for clientId/tenantId that doesn't actually renew the token, hopefully someone can speak to that case as well.

Comment: According to [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-java-get-remove-accounts-token-cache), the in-memory token cache lasts for the duration of the "application" instance, which in this case is the ConfidentialClientApplication instance `cca`.  So the original `cca` value needs to be retained between the time you first get an initial access token and the time you call `acquireTokenSilently(silentParameters)` to obtain a "refreshed" access token.  Also, consider using PublicClientApplication which pops up a web browser page for initial authentication.